# wp_allow_comments checking for blacklisted words effectively

Tags: options, moderation

I have a big list of prohibited words on the DB. The problem Im running to is that no comment is getting through. They are all getting sent to spam. I was looking at comment.php
and found the functions that are handling this. I dont wanna modify the core functions but to write my own. I tried something like `add_action( 'wp_blacklist_check', 'my_wp_blacklist_check');` and pad the words with spaces, so words like 'bi' dont conflict with... let say, the word 'combination'.

Obviously my action did not work is there something Im missing? a different hook or something?

Thank!

Comment: I haven't tried this, but can you not pad the words with spaces from within the WP blacklist admin?

Comment: @vancoder the blacklist function does a `trim()` on all words after being fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_blacklist_check` is an action - it does not return results and does not influence logic.

Hook you want is `pre_comment_approved` filter that gets two arguments - `$approved` (`1`, `0` or `spam` ) and `$commentdata` with comment info.

Use data for your custom processing and return changed `$approved` outcome if needed.